# d3 v4 Hierarchical Edge Bundling

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to move my Hierarchical Edge Bundling chart to d3v4.

but could not find an alternative to d3.layout.bundle().

d3v3 example is https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999

any example with d3v4? Please help.

Comment: Asked a similar question and provided full answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797911/d3-v4-hierarchical-edge-bundling-port-from-v3

Answer (score 3):

You'll need two things: the hierarchy and the array of links between nodes in the hierarchy.

You can load a hierarchy from JSON or create one from CSV by using `d3.stratify`. Then pass the hierarchy to `d3.hierarchy`. See [the d3-hierarchy documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy).

Then you'll need to construct an array of links. Each link is an object with a `source` and `target`, each of which points to a node in the hierarchy.

You can calculate and draw the bundles using a combination of `node.path` (which replaces `d3.layout.bundle`) and `d3.curveBundle`. See [the d3.curveBundle documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveBundle).

If `links` is your array of links, the code looks something like this:

```
const line = d3.line()
  .x(d => d.data.x)
  .y(d => d.data.y)
  .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.95));

const edges = g.selectAll('.link').data(links);

edges.enter().append('path')
  .attr('class', 'link')
.merge(edges)
  .attr('d', d => line(d.source.path(d.target)));

edges.exit().remove();
```