# D3 v4/v5 version of d3 v3 hierarchical Edge Bundling Treemap

Tags: d3.js, treemap

I am trying to reproduce and combine the [D3 v3 Hierarchical edge bundling tree-map](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341134) with the [D3 v4 Zoomable Tree-map](http://bl.ocks.org/ganeshv/6a8e9ada3ab7f2d88022). I'd like to transfer the code logic that draws the link lines to the zoomable tree-map. I'm currently having difficulty finding the D3 v4 equivalent implementation of "d3.layout.bundle()". I have tried d3.bundle() but that just simply fails. I have tried simply copying the v3 line "var bundle = d3.layout.bundle()" but this also fails when referencing v4 library, with the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bundle')"

Where as D3 v3 d3.layout.treemap has been ported to d3.treemap, there does not seem any direct equivalent for d3.layout.bundle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [d3 v4 Hierarchical Edge Bundling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031008/d3-v4-hierarchical-edge-bundling)

Comment: Kind of. Thanks. I was really after its implementation on a D3 tree-map, not on a circular layout (I have already get one of those working as there are plenty of d3 4/v5 examples out there, but the only coded example of edge bundling on a tree-map is for D3 v3.   I'll see if I can break the back of it by modifying the circular visual form into a treemap form.